# Symfony - controller edit action

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, repository-pattern

I defined the form in my controller and set function to edit/update specific fields that I can find by ID. I can't find what am I doing wrong..

```
 public function getUserEdit(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'First Name*', 'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Send', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save'
        ]))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();
        $firstName = $data['firstName'];

        $this->container->get('user')->editUser($firstName);
    }

    return $this->success();
}
```

Service

```
public function editUser($id)
{
    $editUsers = $this->getUserRepository()->find($id);

    if(empty($editUsers)) {
        $editUsers = new User();
        $editUsers->setId($id);
        $this->em->persist($editUsers);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's happening? What do you expect to happen? As written it's hard to understand what's the problem

Comment: Is this the right way to edit existing data from db by ID? I want for function to find my firstName by Id and to edit that field and other ones by Id. I putt just firstName for example but I have 10 fields that needs to be updated by ID..

Comment: There is no single right way. Also what you pasted does no edits at all

Comment: I know easy way is by easyadmin but I want to write a fucntion that can edit my records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony `returns` a single object when searching by `find` primary key (usually `id`), then you can check if exist returns a single `Entity` (in this case `User`) and so that checking by using `insteance`.

```
public function editUser($id)
{
    $editUsers = $this->getUserRepository()->find($id);

    if($editUsers insteance User) { // here just check 
        //$editUsers = new User(); // here You don't need create new object of class User, just remove
        $editUsers->setId($id);
        $this->em->persist($editUsers);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
    else {
        // do something if you need
    }
}
```